# Making the fallback for ALB routing when ECS doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have routing like

`ALB -> rule -> TargetGroup -> ECS on EC2`

```
Rule ARN

If (all match)
HTTP Host Header is example.com
Then
Forward to target group

my-dev-nginx-tg : 1 (100%)
Group-level stickiness: Off
```

My target group `my-dev-nginx-tg` is like this,

[image]

So, this setting works perfect in daytime, and I stop the server during night time.

But,when user accessing at night time, it returns `503` error.

If possible, I would like to return some message when night time.(just say "it's maintanance time")

If possible, I want to return the message from `ALB` or `TargetGroup` level

I know `ALB` has the function, when every rules doesn't much, It can return 404 and message.

However, in this case, it muches the rule, so I cant use this method.

Is there any good idea? or good practice?

Comment: ALB doesn't have any failover feature.  When you stop your server, you'll have to also [add a fixed response to the ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#fixed-response-actions) that returns the desired content and remove or reorder it when you turn the instance back on.

Comment: Mmm I see, I understood the method. However I need to remove or reoder the rules by lambda, because my server is stopped by lambda automatically. I am not sure it is possible or not though....I will try, thank you.

Comment: should be possible with sufficient engineering, like pigs flying.  Kidding, should be a lot easier than pigs flying.  If the state transitions vex your implementation, consider using cloudformation as an infrastructure state machine

Comment: @Erik258 thank you. I found out this is possible. I successfully changed  the rule by lambda It's quite easier than pigs flying. Thank you for encouraging me.